# Python3, download file from url by button click

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, download, urllib

I need to download file from link like this https://freemidi.org/getter-13560

But I cant use `urllib.request` or `requests` library cause it downloads html, not midi. Is there is any solution? And also here is the link with the button itself [link](https://freemidi.org/download-13560-chhaideu-timi-1974-ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the proper headers and using session we can download and save the file using request module.

```
import requests

headers = {
            "Host": "freemidi.org",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
           }

session = requests.Session()

#the website sets the cookies first
req1 = session.get("https://freemidi.org/getter-13560", headers = headers)

#Request again to download
req2 = session.get("https://freemidi.org/getter-13560", headers = headers)
print(len(req2.text))     # This is the size of the mdi file

with open("testFile.mid", "wb") as saveMidi:
    saveMidi.write(req2.content)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's finally working. But there needed some changes. Type req2.content instead of req2.text, choose 'wb' mode and '*.mid', not '*.midi*'